# Want to seperate integers and floats from column with diferent strings in it

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract only integers and floats from column of string 
i have tried 
`data['new'] = data['text'].str.extract(r'^\d+\.\d+$')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need extract only values with numeric:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'text':['20','45.45','ss4','7.4ds','dr']})
data['new'] = data['text'].str.extract(r'^(\d+\.\d+|\d+)$')
print (data)
    text    new
0     20     20
1  45.45  45.45
2    ss4    NaN
3  7.4ds    NaN
4     dr    NaN
```

Then convert to floats:

```
data['new'] = data['text'].str.extract(r'^(\d+\.\d+|\d+)$').astype(float)
print (data)
    text    new
0     20  20.00
1  45.45  45.45
2    ss4    NaN
3  7.4ds    NaN
4     dr    NaN
```

Or use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) function:

```
data['new'] = pd.to_numeric(data['text'], errors='coerce')
print (data)
    text    new
0     20  20.00
1  45.45  45.45
2    ss4    NaN
3  7.4ds    NaN
4     dr    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add capture groups in your regex.

I assumed the simplest case since you didnt provide any example of your data:

```
>> df
               text
0     green123apple
1  yellow45.6banana
```

So here's the new regex: `"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"`

If we split the regex down we get:

The `?:` part means that you don't want to capture this inner group, you don't care about getting the decimal part in a separate group. You just want the whole number.

Output:

```
>> df["new"] = df["text"].str.extract("(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)")
>> df
               text   new
0     green123apple   123
1  yellow45.6banana  45.6
```